# How can I remove the "ytp-mobile-a11y-hidden-seek-button" div to use the YouTube embedded API on mobile web?

Tags: vue.js, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using YouTube Embedded api to display YouTube players on the mobile web, but if I try to import embedded videos of private or non-playable videos during embedded, I get a div with the class "ytp-mobile-a11y-hidden-seek-buton", can you tell me how to get rid of this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g85GW.png)

For your information, I am using vue-youtube-embed to bring a YouTube player, but as a test, even if I use the API of YouTube as it is, there is a problem as shown in the attached picture.